# Are questions about past personal medical issues on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it okay to ask a question based on COVID symptoms that I had well over a year ago? I wouldn't be asking for advice; I'm just curious how common a particular symptom I had is.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Give us a general summary of what you want to ask.

Comment: @CareyGregory the question would be "How common is tachycardia as a symptom of COVID-19?" If details are OK, I would specify in the body that when I had COVID, my resting heart rate at one point was in the high 180s, and that it was during the summer of 2022 (in case knowing what variants were common at the time is relevant). I've already talked to an FNP about this, and she was surprised but not concerned about future effects.

Comment: Why does the question need the anecdote about your personal health? Why can’t it just be “how common is tachycardia with COVID 19 infection? I found this website but am still confused.”

Answer (score 4):

Questions relating to personal health or medical care are off-topic, so you should not include an anecdote about your health.

You can of course ask about how common particular symptoms are. As with any question on Medical Sciences, it is important to provide some evidence of basic research around the question.